# WS-Security: validating a certificate chain with axis2/rampart

Tags: java, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart, jks

I try to encrypt and signature the communication between a soap server and client written in Java/Axis2. Encryption works but when I deleted the root certificate from the java key store, nothing changed. Without the Root Certificate it is not possible to validate the certificates of the server and client. It seems to be that rampart doesn't care about the certificate chain, cause there is no error message. But without the root certificate there has to be an error message!

Do I have to configure the java key store in a special way? It notices, that there exists already a root certificate in the store, cause when I import a normel certificate from the chain from openssl, everything is ok and there are no questions like: Do you want to trust the new certificate?

Or do I have to configure rampart to test the certification chain?